# Aurelia and Shadow DOM

Tags: aurelia, shadow-dom

I'm coming from Polymer and am wondering if and how Aurelia supports Shadow DOM and related features that Polymer supports. I see mention that Aurelia supports Shadow DOM v1 slots, which works fine, but I can't enable Shadow DOM - I assumed that there was a Polyfill since v1 isn't implemented yet, or something like the Polymer Shady DOM?

My main interest in Shadow DOM is style encapsulation. Polymer allows styling of the generated container element using the :host selector from within the template - does Aurelia allow something similar?

```
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</template>
```

Also, is there a polyfill for CSS variables, like Polymer (essential for Shadow DOM)?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging - Aurelia only supports Shadow DOM V1 *via* native browser support (apart from slots), so even if you enable Shadow DOM support nothing happens because browsers don't support it yet.